# Creating new column using column header and row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is indexed by date, with time as separate columns for each row. Not ideal for comparison. *RecordDate* is an object while the time columns are float64.

My initial idea was to convert to datetime and look to merge, however, I understand this wouldn't work due to the time being a column header.

Here is an example of my data set:

```
  RecordDate    T0000   T0030   T0100   T0130   T0200   T0230   T0300
    15/04/2015  0        0       0       0       0       0       0
    16/04/2015  0        0       0       0       0       0       0
    17/04/2015  0        0       0       0       0       0       0
    18/04/2015  0        0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Here is an example of my ideal outcome:

```
RecordDate           Value
15/04/2015 00:00       0
15/04/2015 00:30       0
15/04/2015 01:00       0
```

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.melt` method.
For example for following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "RecordDate": ["15/04/2015", "16/04/2015"],
    "T0000": [1, 2],
    "T0030": [3, 4]
})
df.melt(id_vars=["RecordDate"], var_name="RecordHour")
```

gives output

```
   RecordDate RecordHour  value
0  15/04/2015      T0000      1
1  16/04/2015      T0000      2
2  15/04/2015      T0030      3
3  16/04/2015      T0030      4
```

Then columns `RecordDate` and `RecordHour` can be combined to one `datetime` column.